# sp_executesql Parameters Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a table that can be modified my the user, meaning the user can add columns, since i cant know how many columns does de table will have, I dont know how can i supply the sp_executesql values.

My code so far:

```
SET @sSQL = (
    N'INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
    VALUES('+@numParametros+')'
)

--For Explaining purposes since @stmtPar is SET dynamically 
--in a while-loop at de begining of the SP
SET @ParmDefinition = @stmtPar
```

Here is where i need help, due to the fact that i dont know how many columns does the table has I cant know how many @parameters i need to supply

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sSql, @ParmDefinition, ????
```

I have a @values variable that contains the values that need to be inserted but if i put the next statment sql only uses @values fo supply the first column

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sSql, @ParmDefinition, @values
```

Hope you can help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the number of parameters you should build a SQL statement manually. Here is an example (third column has the varchar type and double quotas are used):

```
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @numParametros NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @numParametros = '1,2,''test''';

SET @sSQL = (
    N'INSERT INTO Table1
    VALUES('+@numParametros+')'
)
exec sp_executesql @sSQL
```